# Hebrews 12:27 What is ὡς comparing to what?

Tags: grammar, hebrews, kingdom-of-god

Most translations render Hebrews 12:27 as something like the following:

> 27 This phrase, "Yet once more," indicates the removal of things that are shaken—**that is [ὡς],** things that have been made—in order that the things that cannot be shaken may remain.

I understand the word ὡς to be an adverb of comparison; however, most translations of Heb 12:27 translate it more like an equation saying what something "is" instead of a comparison saying what something is "like."

Is this accurate? If so, how can we tell when "is" is meant instead of "like" or "as"?

If this is not accurate, and we should understand ὡς as more comparative, how should the comparison work?

Should we understand that God will be removing things in a manner somehow comparable to how he has made things?

Comment: The _comparison_ is between 'things that are shaken' and 'things that cannot be not shaken'. 'Things that are made' is one example of 'things that are shaken'. _Such as_ would be a correct translation.

Answer (score 1):

This is uncomplicated - the adverb ὡς (hos) serves quite a number of functions - BDAG lists nine such purposes of this adverb - see appendix below.

Specifically, BDAG lists meaning #3 for Heb 12:27 below which acts as a kind of clarification.  Thus, in Heb 12:27 we effectively have:

> ... the things being shaken, that is, things having been created ...

Thus, the writer is saying that the only things that will be shaken are the things that have been created, with the clear (and explicit in the next phrase) implication that uncreated things will not be shaken..

[There is some deep theology here that, in some circles, is very controversial but I will not enter that realm.]

**APPENDIX - BDAG entry for ὡς**

here I list only the headline meanings for this word in BDAG.

1. a comparative particle marking the manner in which something proceeds, as, like
2. a conjunction marking a point of comparison, as
3. marker introducing the perspective from which a person, thing, or activity is viewed or understood as to character or function, or role, as, eg, **Heb 12:27**
4. conjunction: marker of result in connection with indication of purpose, so that
5. marker of discourse content, that, the fact that
6. with numerals: a degree that approximates a point on a scale of extent, about, approximately, nearly
7. a relatively high point on a scale involving exclamation, how!
8. temporal conjunction
9. a final particle, expressing intention/purpose, with a view to, in order that